# How to display a message + images based on a calculated chance depending on the variables value

Tags: javascript, image, math, display, percentage

So as the title suggests i am trying to show images based on a percentage. The higher that the variables value is, the higher chance it will show the succes message + the right images. But for some reason it keeps showing the failed message even if the variable is high enough to be in the 80% chance category:

```js
function mission1(user_power) {
if (user_power < 5) {
if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
document.getElementById('missionpopup').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('popupdarkness').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsucces').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsuccestext').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsuccestext').innerHTML = "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didn't run into any trouble."
document.getElementById('expgain').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('itemfound').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('approvalimg').style.visibility = "visible"
}
} else if (user_power == 5) {
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
document.getElementById('missionpopup').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('popupdarkness').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsucces').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsuccestext').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsuccestext').innerHTML = "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didn't run into any trouble."
document.getElementById('expgain').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('itemfound').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('approvalimg').style.visibility = "visible"
}
} else if (user_power > 5) {
if (Math.random() < 0.8) {
document.getElementById('missionpopup').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('popupdarkness').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsucces').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsuccestext').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionsuccestext').innerHTML = "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didn't run into any trouble."
document.getElementById('expgain').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('itemfound').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('approvalimg').style.visibility = "visible"
}
} else {
document.getElementById('missionpopup').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('popupdarkness').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionfailed').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('missionfailuretext').style.visibility = "visible"
document.getElementById('denialimg').style.visibility = "visible"
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong in this code?

Comment: It's tons of duplicate code, is the main thing you're doing wrong. Use a short if-else if block to set some variable to 0.5 or 0.8 etc based on the power, then do a single Math.random() check. Also the first three blocks are already covering all possible values for user_power, so the final else block will never run.

Comment: Could you give a small example, because i am not 100% sure what you mean. The final else block is running and its the only thing that it shows back as i mentioned in the post.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rufec3vw/

Comment: Ah thanks, i had no idea that you could write it like that.

Comment: No worries, it's not like I wrote code like that when I was a beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yet another solution with keeping the original code**

```js
let userPower = 1;

// Show all images by their ids
function showImages(...ids) {
  ids.forEach(id => (document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible"));
}

// Show message on an element by ids id
function showMessage(id, message) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = message;
}

function mission1() {
  // Chance
  const chance = Math.random();

  if (userPower < 5 && chance < 0.3) {
    // Show images
    showImages("missionpopup", "popupdarkness", "missionsucces", "missionsuccestext");

    // Show a message
    showMessage(
      "missionsuccestext",
      "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didn't run into any trouble."
    );

    // Show images
    showImages("expgain", "itemfound", "approvalimg");

    return;
  }

  if (userPower == 5 && chance < 0.5) {
    // Show images
    showImages("missionpopup", "popupdarkness", "missionsucces", "missionsuccestext");

    // Show a message
    showMessage(
      "missionsuccestext",
      "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didn't run into any trouble."
    );

    // Show images
    showImages("expgain", "itemfound", "approvalimg");
    return;
  }

  if (userPower > 5 && chance < 0.8) {
    // Show images
    showImages("missionpopup", "popupdarkness", "missionsucces", "missionsuccestext");

    // Show a message
    showMessage(
      "missionsuccestext",
      "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didn't run into any trouble."
    );

    // Show images
    showImages("expgain", "itemfound", "approvalimg");

    return;
  }

  showImages("missionpopup", "popupdarkness", "missionfailed", "missionfailuretext", "denialimg");
}
```